# Why is a MAPI call failing?

Tags: exchange, blackberry

I am installing an emergency pin to pin messaging system server, and Im trying to tell this program to look at our exchange server, however whenever it tries to validate anything (the email addresses i created for the program) i get a "MAPI failed to initialize" message with an error code that means the call failed.

I am unfamiliar with MAPI and how it functions, so any insight would be helpful.

Comment: The software is called METAmessage

Answer (score 1):

MAPI is the library used for communicating with Exchange.  It is not part of Windows by default and needs to be added by either installing Outlook or the [Exchange Server MAPI Client](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e17e7f31-079a-43a9-bff2-0a110307611e&displaylang=en)

Also, a MAPI profile typically needs to be created which contains the information on which Exchange server to talk to and what mailbox to connect with.  This will depend on the software being used.  I would check the documentation for the product on how to configure MAPI for it's use.

Answer (score 0):

Like Joe Doyle said it could be a profile problem.  There might be an authentication issue as well.

One further thing is that MS released an update to MAPI such that a user will be prompted with a "Something is programatically accessing your profile, do you want to allow this" prompt whenever something tries to get into a profile.  This was done because of the prevalence of malicious code hooking into address lists and whatnot via MAPI.  If your app was written before this update it could be that it's not handling this prompt correctly.

Comment: how exactly would i determine this? assuming it is the case.

Comment: @kyoung: I'm not really sure because I don't know how exactly METAmessage works.  Have you contacted their tech support?